# Apache - Redirect on File Format

Tags: php, apache

I want to cause my website to redirect on a specific file format.

For example: if you go to .../image.png, i want to show the user my domain on the top and the requested image below. the browser shall not show the image with the built-in image-viewer.

Is that possible?

My thought would be, to redirect to a PHP File with a $_GET Request:

```
$img = $_GET['img'];

echo '<html><body><p>My Domain</p><img src="' . $img . '"></img>';
```

Apache should redirect to .../image.php?img=Requested Image Url

Comment: No. You can't *reliably* differentiate between direct URL requests, and such originating from HTML references like `<img src=>`.

Comment: @mario is absolutely right. With your method you could easily end up creating an infinite loop of requests. Apache doesn't care if the image is requested as part of a page or requested by someone entering it.

Comment: But some image pages manage it, to use her own design vor .png or .jpg requests. how do they do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into AliasMatch in the configuration file. Adding something like

```
    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.png) /path/to/file
```

might work. The configuration file exists in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf for me.

There is some more information about Alias here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html